# How to retrieve well formatted JSON from AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I have a function in AWS Lambda that connects to the Twitter API and returns the tweets which match a specific search query I provided via the event. A simplified version of the function is below. There's a few helper functions I use like `get_secret` to manage API keys and `process_tweet` which limits what data gets sent back and does things like convert the created at date to a string. The net result is that I should get back a list of dictionaries.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    twitter_secret = get_secret("twitter")

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(twitter_secret['api-key'],
                               twitter_secret['api-secret'])
    auth.set_access_token(twitter_secret['access-key'],
                          twitter_secret['access-secret'])
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q=event['search'],
                           include_entities=True,
                           tweet_mode='extended',
                           lang='en')

    tweets = list(cursor.items())
    tweets = [process_tweet(t) for t in tweets if not t.retweeted]

    return json.dumps({"tweets": tweets})
```

From my desktop then, I have code which invokes the lambda function.

```
aws_lambda = boto3.client('lambda', region_name="us-east-1")
payload = {"search": "paint%20protection%20film filter:safe"}
lambda_response = aws_lambda.invoke(FunctionName="twitter-searcher",
                                    InvocationType="RequestResponse",
                                    Payload=json.dumps(payload))
results = lambda_response['Payload'].read()
tweets = results.decode('utf-8')
```

The problem is that somewhere between `json.dumps`ing the output in lambda and reading the payload in Python, the data has gotten screwy.  For example, a line break which should be `\n` becomes `\\\\n`, all of the double quotes are stored as `\\"` and Unicode characters are all prefixed by `\\`. So, everything that was escaped, when it was received by Python on my desktop with the escaping character being escaped. Consider this element of the list that was returned (with manual formatting).

```
'{\\"userid\\": 190764134,
  \\"username\\": \\"CapitalGMC\\",
  \\"created\\": \\"2018-09-02 15:00:00\\",
  \\"tweetid\\": 1036267504673337344,
  \\"text\\": \\"Protect your vehicle\'s paint! Find out how on this week\'s blog.
              \\\\ud83d\\\\udc47\\\\n\\\\nhttps://url/XYMxPhVhdH https://url/mFL2Zv8nWW\\"}'
```

I can use regex to fix some problems (`\\"` and `\\\\n`) but the Unicode is tricky because even if I match it, how do I replace it with a properly escaped character?  When I do this in R, using the `aws.lambda` package, everything is fine, no weird escaped escapes.

**What am I doing wrong on my desktop with the response from AWS Lambda that's garbling the data?**

### Update

The process tweet function is below. It literally just pulls out the bits I care to keep, formats the datetime object to be a string and returns a dictionary.

```
def process_tweet(tweet):
    bundle = {
        "userid": tweet.user.id,
        "username": tweet.user.screen_name,
        "created": str(tweet.created_at),
        "tweetid": tweet.id,
        "text": tweet.full_text
    }
    return bundle
```

Just for reference, in R the code looks like this.

```
payload = list(search="paint%20protection%20film filter:safe")
results = aws.lambda::invoke_function("twitter-searcher"
                                      ,payload = jsonlite::toJSON(payload
                                                              ,auto_unbox=TRUE)
                                      ,type = "RequestResponse"
                                      ,key = creds$key
                                      ,secret = creds$secret
                                      ,session_token = creds$session_token
                                      ,region = creds$region)
tweets = jsonlite::fromJSON(results)
str(tweets)

#> 'data.frame':    133 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ userid  : num  2231994854 407106716 33553091 7778772 782310 ...
#>  $ username: chr  "adaniel_080213" "Prestige_AdamL" "exclusivedetail" "tedhu" ...
#>  $ created : chr  "2018-09-12 14:07:09" "2018-09-12 11:31:56" "2018-09-12 10:46:55" "2018-09-12 07:27:49" ...
#>  $ tweetid : num  1039878080968323072 1039839019989983232 1039827690151444480 1039777586975526912 1039699310382931968 ...
#>  $ text    : chr  "I liked a @YouTube video https://url/97sRShN4pM Tesla Model 3 - Front End Package - Suntek Ultra Paint Protection Film" "Another #Corvette #ZO6 full body clearbra wrap completed using @xpeltech ultimate plus PPF ... Paint protection"| __truncated__ "We recently protected this Tesla Model 3 with Paint Protection Film and Ceramic Coating.#teslamodel3 #charlotte"| __truncated__ "Tesla Model 3 - Front End Package - Suntek Ultra Paint Protection Film https://url/AD1cl5dNX3" ...

tweets[131,]
#>        userid   username             created             tweetid
#> 131 190764134 CapitalGMC 2018-09-02 15:00:00 1036267504673337344
#>          text
#> 131 Protect your vehicle's paint! Find out how on this week's blog.\n\nhttps://url/XYMxPhVhdH https://url/mFL2Zv8nWW
```

Comment: It looks like `tweets` in `{"tweets": tweets}` might be going in as a string or list of strings. What does `process_tweet` do? Also, what's a sample `t` in `for t in tweets` look like? I imagine it's a dict, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: @wholevinski I posted the code for `process_tweet`, the `t` for `t in tweets` is a `tweepy` object, you can see how I access it in `process_tweet`. I also show how connecting to the same AWS Lambda function from another language doesn't produce the same issue.

Comment: I totally missed something...can you add a `json.loads(lambda_response['Payload'].read())` when you get your response payload?

Comment: `json.loads(results).__class__()` results in `''` while `json.loads(json.loads(results)).__class__()` results in `{}`
Why do I need to do `json.loads` twice?

Comment: You shouldn't need it twice. Maybe I missed something but your original code you're calling from your desktop didn't have the `json.loads` which is why I was suggesting it. I'm not sure I follow on your question about calling it twice though. What does `lambda_response['Payload'].read()` look like for a sample tweet(s) without any json conversion, unicode decoding, or anything?

Comment: `b'{\\"userid\\": 190764134, \\"username\\": \\"CapitalGMC\\", \\"created\\": \\"2018-09-02 15:00:00\\", \\"tweetid\\": 1036267504673337344, \\"text\\": \\"Protect your vehicle\'s paint! Find out how on this week\'s blog.\\\\ud83d\\\\udc47\\\\n\\\\nhttps://url/XYMxPhVhdH https://url/mFL2Zv8nWW\\"}'`

Comment: Yeah...it sure looks like your return dict is being double encoded. Does the response payload look the same when calling it from R? Everything looks right on the python side. If you're comfortable doing it, I would maybe log the response from the lambda side before you send it too. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: `return json.dumps({"tweets": tweets})` is wrong.  You want to `return {"tweets": tweets}`.  The function returns a dictionary; Lambda returns a JSON representation of it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Huh, that would explain the double encoding then. Couldn't find that anywhere in the AWS documentation. EDIT: Nevermind: 'AWS Lambda returns the result of the Python function call to the client invoking the Lambda function (in the HTTP response to the invocation request, serialized into JSON)'

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that fixed it, thanks. If you write it up as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: @Mark, what was your experience using R on/for lambda, and your reason for wanting to do it in python (maybe the first even answers the second :p)

Comment: @DaveRGP I've never written a lambda function that ran R. I consume lambda output agnostic-ally, just use whatever language makes the most sense for the project. I think in this case it was just an excuse to figure out how to do this in Python so I could personally learn and also teach my coworkers how to do it.

Answer (score 25):

In your lambda function you should return a response object with a JSON object in the response body.

```py
# Lambda Function
def get_json(event, context):
    """Retrieve JSON from server."""
    # Business Logic Goes Here.
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {},
        "body": json.dumps({
            "message": "This is the message in a JSON object."
        })
    }
    return response
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `json.dumps()`

I had a similar issue, and when I just returned `"body": content` instead of `"body": json.dumps(content)` I could easily access and manipulate my data. Before that, I got that weird form that looks like JSON, but it's not.